# Following point using force

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, physics, monogame

I'm trying to make my `Entity.cs` `Follow(Vector2 point)` any point in the map. This has to be done using "force". Force is a `Vector2` of `Entity` that is used to move the `Entity` across the map. On every `Update(float elapsedTime)` of `Entity`, `Entity` is moved by `Force * elapsedTime`. Like this:

```
public virtual void Update (float elapsedTime)
{
    position += force * elapsedTime;
}
```

So, I want to create a function similar to `Update` function, called `Follow`, which will be adding enough force to the `Entity` so that it moves to the point, and stops when it reaches that point.

This could be used by bullet class (child of `Entity`) to follow an enemy, or something like that, I beleave you can all see what I'd use that for in the game.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
public virtual void Follow (Vector2 follow, float intensity)
{
    if (position != follow) AddForce((follow - position) * intensity);
    else AddForce(-force);
}
```

And the code calling this function looks like this

```
Follow(followThisPoint, 300 * elapsedTime);
```

Note that this line is called on every `Update`, and that is how I'd like to be.

The problem I'm having with this function is that too much force is added to the entity, and it just passes right trough the point where I want it to be, and then, when it passes, it slows down, and tries to go back, but then I get the same result I just described, but in opposite direction.

I'd like to have control of how fast the `Entity` will follow the point of interest, and to have it stop instantly at the point of interest, or slow down when near, and stop on that point slowly.

**Edit 1:** As requested, here is the `AddForce` function:

```
public void AddForce (Vector2 addForce)
{
    force += addForce;
}
```

Comment: Can you add 'AddForce' function to your question. From a brief think, I would reduce the intensity value passed to follow - (in your above case - reduce the 300, Why not make that value 1) and see if it really slows. AND what's the value of force (referenced in your Follow function)?

Comment: Continued - When you are at the destination point, wouldn't you use (-force*elapsedtime) instead of just (-force)?

Comment: yea, (-force*elapsedtime) is the right one, but I never even got to that, so i could never see that line of code in action. The '300' is the intensity, so, if i just put 1, i will get the same result, but much, much slower. so that isn't the real problem. I will now add AddForce function to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer the question, I want to clarify some terminology.

Your variable `force` is actually a velocity. It represents how fast an object travels. A force can change an object's velocity via acceleration. If you apply a force to an object, this object is accelerated. The effect on the velocity depends on how long the force is applied and on the object's mass.

Given that, let's take a look at your question. You want to apply a force, such that the resulting velocity vector is:

```
vTarget = (follow - position) * intensity
```

This implies that the velocity drops to zero when the object reaches the target. You can also limit the velocity to an upper bound.

Given your `AddForce` definition, you have to apply the following force `F`:

```
vTarget            = vCurrent + F
vTarget - vCurrent = F
```

Again, you can limit the length of `F`. And this is all there is. Here is some C#/pseudo code:

```
public virtual void Follow (Vector2 follow, float intensity)
{
    float vMax = 1000;
    float fMax = 1000;
    Vector2 vTarget = (follow - position) * intensity;
    if (vTarget.Length() > vMax) vTarget = vTarget * (vMax / vTarget.Length());
    Vector2 force = vTarget - this.force; //where this.force is actually the velocity
    if (force.Length() > fMax) force = force * (fMax / force.Length());
    AddForce(force);
}
```